# How would I create an IO Bool that returns True for a while, then False thereafter?

Tags: haskell

Today I was trying to deepen my understanding of the IO monad, and I tried to write a function that take an `Int` `n` and returns an `IO Bool` than produces `True` `n` times, then `False` forever afterwards.

```
trueThenFalse :: Int -> IO Bool
```

Normally I'd address something like this with recursion, but here there seems to be nothing to recurse into.

How would I go about implementing this function?  Is it possible and/or advisable to do so?

Comment: I think you want `Int -> IO (IO Bool)` instead?

Comment: No.  In (perhaps) my naïveté, I want something akin to `getLine`, which is an `IO String`, not an `IO (IO String)`.  If the `Int` parameter complicates things, then what about a simple `trueThenFalse :: IO Bool` which produces one `True`, then `False`s forever after?

Comment: That is possible with a global state, but you will get only one counter (as `getLine` has only one input stream). More to the point `do let x = trueThenFalse 2 ; a1 <- x ; a2 <- x ; print (a1,a2)` must be equivalent to `do let x= trueThenFalse 2 ; y = trueThenFalse 2 ; a1 <- x ; a2 <- y ; print (a1,a2)`. You can not distinguish between `x` and `y` since they are defined in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might make more sense as an `IO (IO Bool)`, because you have to set up some state first:

```
trueThenFalse n = do
  holder <- newMVar n
  return (modifyMVar holder (\ k -> return (k - 1, k > 0)))
```

That creates a mutable holder to store the count of how many Trues are "left," and returns another `IO` operation which can be run multiple times, modifying the count and returning `True` if the count was > 0.

Comment: Could always use unsafePerformIO to create the MVar.

Comment: Sure, but then you have to worry about how every time you use unsafePerformIO, a kitten dies, and eventually the ASPCA shows up at your door and everything's terrible.

Comment: Nested `IO` is incredibly important. It drives home why `IO` is a real type, not just some sort of impurity flag.

Comment: The state variable hasn't to be an `MVar`, an `IORef` should do unless you plan to use `trueThenFalse` in multiple threads.

Comment: @ItaiZukerman, using `unsafePerformIO` will also make it very very difficult to make sure you have the number of `MVar`s (or `IORef`s) that you think you do. The headaches may never end.

Comment: I've conceptualized `IO a` simply as a computation that produces a (probably) different `a` each time it's bound to a function.  It's not clear to me why such a thing cannot be written "directly" (like `getLine`, an `IO String` rather than an `IO (IO String)`) without bringing in what amounts to a mutable variable, something otherwise rarely needed in functional programming, as far as I've seen.

Comment: You need to setup state, essentially, unless you want all occurrences of this method to use the same counter.  Two calls to trueThenFalse must refer to different counters.

Comment: Okay, but why can't such state simply reside in a bare `IO Bool`?  If I've conceptualized `IO Bool` correctly as "a computation that produces a different `Bool` each time it's bound to a function," then why can't the state just be part of the opaque "computation"?

Comment: If you call tTF 3 once, and tTF 3 again, those must use independent counts. Those must return two different IO actions which modify different counters. This requires another IO wrapping.  In your phrasing, it must be a different computation each time.

Comment: Why can't a function returning an `IO Bool` return a different computation each time?  A function returning an `Int` can obviously return a different `Int` each time.

Comment: That second statement is false; Haskell functions must return the same value on the same input each time.  Understand that, and you'll understand the answer to your question.

Comment: I can't see how.  As perhaps the most obvious counterexample, `id 1 == 1`, `id 2 == 2`, etc.  Different return values, depending on its parameter.  I specifically referred to a "function returning an `IO Bool`", which clearly implies that the return value could depend on the parameter.

Comment: On the same input, you must always return the same result. As I understand it, tTF n must return different results for the same n, where the results are themselves computations.

Comment: Not as I understand it.  `trueThenFalse 3` would return a computation that produces `True` three times, then `False`s.  Calling it again would return a computation that also produces `True` three times, then `False`s.  Isn't this the same return value?

Comment: No, it's not, it's an independent counter. The same return value would only return true three times for the life of the program.  There could only ever be one IO Bool, which could only be used three times ever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70748/discussion-between-sean-and-louis-wasserman).

Comment: Each call to tTF n must yield an operation with state independent of each other call, and you can't do that without IO.  This is not true of e.g. readLine.